# Regex formula to scope a group and pull a value from it

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a quick inquiry about a regex formula, I am trying to pull group membership via a regex function, in my task I have for example a group named `SSO-TEST-Admin`,
I would like to know if I can filter the group via something like: 
`.*SSO-TEST-.*` basically scoping all groups matching the `SSO-TEST-`, after I get the group, transform the result to give only the `Admin` portion from it or whatever value is after the `SSO-TEST-`.

I have tested: `(?(?=(SSO-TEST*))SSO-TEST-ADMIN|SSO-TEST-ReadOnly-admin)`, but was unsuccessful. Appreciate any hint.

Comment: I can't really follow what you're asking, but `^SSO-TEST-(ReadOnly-admin|ADMIN)$` could be all you need. Example: https://regex101.com/r/UE8ofs/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind to match the `SSO-TEST-` prefix and return the words after it.

```
(?<=SSO-TEST-)[\w\-]+
```

`[\w\-]+` will match word characters and hyphens after the prefix.